# VichUploaderBundle: How to get related entity ID in DirectoryNamer?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, vichuploaderbundle

I am configuring a [directory namer](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/namers.md) included in [VichUploaderBundle](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle) to upload multiple files.

I have two entities `Soundtrack` and `Song`. The collection of `Song`s are processed in my controller like this:

```
//...
if ($form->isValid()) {
   $soundtrack->setSlug("sw-ep-vii");
   $soundtrack->setName("Star Wars Episode VII");
   foreach ($soundtrack->getSongs() as $song) {
      $em->persist($song);
   }
   $em->persist($soundtrack);
   $em->flush();
}
```

When persisting `$soundtrack` `VichUploaderBundle` uploads the `Song` files and moves them to the directory defined in `config.yml` or to a dynamic route defined in a service called `DirectoryNamer`, which is the one i'm interested.

In my `SoundtrackDirectoryNamer`, the persisting `Song` entity is automagically passed to the `directoryName()` method so i want to just return the associated `Soundtrack.id` as a directory name like:

```
class SoundtrackDirectoryNamer implements DirectoryNamerInterface
{
    public function directoryName($song, PropertyMapping $mapping)
    {   
        return $song->getSoundtrack()->getId();                                                                                    
    }
}
```

Now the problem is `Soundtrack` is still not persisted to the database so it has no auto-incremented `id` yet.

If I change `$song->getSoundtrack()->getId()` to `$song->getSoundtrack()->getSlug()`, it creates the directory `sw-ep-vii` correctly and everything works fine - as i previously set the slug in the controller with `$soundtrack->setSlug("sw-ep-vii")`.

Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the current maintainer of the bundle.

That's a known issue (to be exact, it's more a *won't fix*).

The directory and file name are computed **before** the entity is actually saved, so for new objects the identifier is unavailable. By design, there is nothing that can be done to avoid this… except if you don't use auto-incremented identifiers but generated ones (UUIDs or slugs for instance).

Comment: Thank you K-Phoen, in that case i'm finally doing it with the slug. Anyway, kudos to your efforts on this great bundle!

Comment: Thank you. Is there a work around to generate slugs before the entity is saved ?

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a solution even if it might not be totally robust in all situations. Here is an example method compatible with MySQL that you can put in your namer class to get the expected id of the new entity (presupposes an injected entity manager):

```
protected function getNextAutoIncrementedId($object) {
  $meta = $this->em->getClassMetadata(get_class($object));
  if(!$meta) return null;

  $conn = $this->em->getConnection();
  $table = $meta->getTableName();
  $sql = "SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE `Name` = '$table'";
  $result = $conn->query($sql)->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  if(empty($result['Auto_increment'])) return null;

  return $result['Auto_increment'];
}
```